# How to move child of column above keyboard instead of whole column?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I have tried moving the entire screen above the keyboard using singleChildScrollView using the property reverse: true. But I just want to move the bottom container above the keyboard like in the google keep notes app.

Edit:-

[image: I want to move my container like this when keyboard opens]

Edit 2:- This is the container I want to be above the keyboard. It's a part of the Column.

[Screenshot of my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDaNh.jpg)

This is my container code.

````
  Container controlButtons() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border:
            Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).textSelectionColor, width: 0.3),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Row(
          //row of back and next button
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: controlBack,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  (index != 0) ? const Text('Back') : const Text('Cancel'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: controlNext,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  (index != 3) ? const Text('Next') : const Text('Save'),
                  const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }```

[![My App Screen Screenshot][2]][2]
````

Comment: Sorry to say but your statements are still unable to understandable. please elaborate properly. I'll surely help you if things get understandable.

Comment: @ShrutiRamnandanSharma I have added a keep notes screenshot in which the container comes above the keyboard. I want to implement the same on my container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way here would be to use an `Expanded` widget to 'stretch' what is the note in Keep, such that the button bar aligns to the end.

```dart
return Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyNoteEnteringField(),
    ),
    MyButtonBarAboveKeyboard(),
  ],
);
```

This should align the button bar, which should have a set height, to the end of the page: With the keyboard closed it aligns to the bottom of the screen, with the keyboard opened it moves up to right above the keyboard.

Comment: my container is a part of a column. It's the last child. I just want this one to come above the keyboard leaving others untouched.

Comment: Then you should also be able to put an 'empty' `Expanded` widget in between them, to ensure your container gets pushed all the way down

Answer (score 0):

use `Expanded` Widget, such that bottom bar aligns to the end.

```
children: [
    Expanded(
      child: 'Do stuff here'
    ),
    (.....
  ],
```

Comment: hey bro i put my textfield into expanded and removed the height i assigned to the container containing column  and it worked. Thanks bud.

Comment: Great! That's good.